# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una cierta fila a una columna en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

la verdad he encontrado algunas preguntas respecto a este hilo.
Pero no logro entender algunos conceptos de mysql.
Tengo este tipo de tabla.
Las cuales posee 5 columnas.

```
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|id|empresa_principal|nombre completo|  fechas   | centros |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|1 |     A           |    FELIPE     | 16-08-2019|  C555   |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|2 |     A           |    FELIPE     | 17-08-2019|  C444   |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|3 |     A           |    FELIPE     | 18-08-2019|  C555   |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|4 |     A           |    JUAN       | 16-08-2019|  C555   |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
```

y necesito que pueda quedar de esta forma.

```
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|id|empresa_principal|nombre completo| 16-08-2019| 17-08-2019 | 18-08-2019|
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|1 |     A           |    FELIPE     |    C555   |   C444     |    C555   |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|2 |     A           |    JUAN       |    C555   |            |           |
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

Lo que necesito sobre esto, es que la columna fecha, pueda ser convertida con las fechas generadas por las filas. 
Y además los valores que se guardan en la columna centros,  se puedan almacenar con las nuevas columnas de fechas.

¿Alguna idea respecto a esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una solución es crear las columnas usando los distintos valores en los registros

### Solución estática:

```
SELECT id, empresa_principal, nombre_completo,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fechas = "16-08-2019" THEN centros ELSE NULL END) AS "16-08-2019",
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fechas = "17-08-2019" THEN centros ELSE NULL END) AS "17-08-2019",
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fechas = "18-08-2019" THEN centros ELSE NULL END) AS "18-08-2019"
FROM info 
GROUP BY nombre_completo
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0cad/1/0)</kbd>

Obviamente esto no sirve cuando los valores muchos.

---

### Solución dinámica:

Lo que podemos hacer es crear mediante una consulta utilizando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `CONCAT` una cadena con "las columnas de las fechas".

Luego creamos una cadena con la consulta y concatenamos la cadena de "las columnas de las fechas".

Por último ejecutamos la cadena de la consulta

#### Ejemplo:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

# Creamos "las columnas de las fechas"
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fechas = "',
      fechas,
      '" THEN centros ELSE NULL END) AS "',
      fechas,
      '"'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM info;

# Creamos la consulta agregando "las columnas de las fechas"
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT id, empresa_principal, nombre_completo, ',
    @sql,
    ' FROM info GROUP BY nombre_completo'
  );

# Ejecutamos la consulta
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

#### Ejemplo en `PHP`

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
$con->query("SET @sql = NULL");
$con->query("SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CONCAT('GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fechas = \"', 
        fechas, '\" THEN centros ELSE NULL END) AS '
        , '\"', fechas, '\"'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM info");
$con->query("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, empresa_principal, nombre_completo, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM info 
    GROUP BY nombre_completo')");

$con->query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql");
$stmt = $con->query("EXECUTE stmt");
$con->query("DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt");
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo $con->error;
} else {

    $result= $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($result);
}
```

#### Ejemplo `PHP` - Consultas simples:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CONCAT('GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN fechas = \"', 
        fechas, '\" THEN centros ELSE NULL END) AS '
        , '\"', fechas, '\"')) AS cols
    FROM info");
$data = $stmt->fetch_assoc();

$stmt = $con->query("SELECT
        id, empresa_principal, nombre_completo, {$data['cols']} 
    FROM info 
    GROUP BY nombre_completo");
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo $con->error;
} else {

    $result= $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($result);
}
```

---

#### Créditos

- [Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329361/3791844)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @Marcos, me funcionó correctamente la opción estática, pero me complica no realizarlo de forma dinámica.