# ¿Cómo puedo separar un arreglo por medio de un índice?

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente `for` con una consulta a la base de datos que me trae la `fecha` y la suma de todos los padecimientos que hay en un mismo día,

```
$arr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($c_diag); $i++) { 

$pad_totales_diarios = consultaBDRegresaArray('padecimientos_diarios','fecha, SUM(total) AS total',"fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' AND clave_padecimiento = $c_diag[$i] GROUP BY fecha ", 'A', false);

foreach ($pad_totales_diarios as $clave => $valor) {

    $arr[] = $valor['fecha'].$valor['total'];

}

$arr[]="separador"; 


}


var_dump($arr);
```

Agrego la cadena `"separador"` para saber cuando termina el primer barrido de información.

Recortando demasiado tengo una salida así:

```
array(1614) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "2017-01-0151"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "2017-01-0270"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "2017-01-03111"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "2017-01-0479"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "2017-01-05109"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "separador"
  [6]=>
  string(12) "2017-01-0745"
  [7]=>
  string(13) "2017-01-08100"
  [8]=>
  string(12) "2017-01-0997"
  [9]=>
  string(13) "2017-01-10108"
  [10]=>
  string(12) "2017-01-1192"
}
```

Después necesito separar o recortar el `array` con `array_slice` pero necesito conocer el índice dónde se encuentra "separador", pero como comento anteriormente son varias consultas entonces "separador" viene varias veces, alguna idea de cómo podría realizarlo u otra alternativa de cómo almacenar por separado en otros arreglos, de antemano gracias.

TODO esto me lleva a realizar una gráfica en **AnyChart** donde tengo que armar una estructura como esta:

```
['1986', 3.6, 2.3, 2.8],
['1987', 7.1, 4.0, 4.1],
['1988', 8.5, 6.2, 5.1],
['1989', 9.2, 11.8, 6.5],
```

Dónde la primer columna es el valor de la fecha y las siguientes son el padecimiento1, pad2, etc., pero necesito un arreglo así para validar las fechas por ejemplo en el primer barrido de información las fechas estan completas osea los 365 días del año pero en el segundo se reportaron por ejemplo 290, entonces tengo que comparar que fechas existen en el primer barrido y en el segundo para así las que no existean agregarles un **0** y completar la información de la gráfica.

Comment: Pues si resultaria mejor en un multi-dimensional, al final necesito agregar esa información de esta manera  `['1986', 3.6, 2.3],
        ['1987', 7.1, 4.0],
        ['1988', 8.5, 6.2],
        ['1989', 9.2, 11.8],
        ['1990', 10.1, 13.0],` dónde la primer columna es el valor de la fecha y las siguientes columnas son el valor total de padecimiento1, padecimiento2, etc, es para realizar una grafica en **AnyChart**.

Comment: Ya agregué la demás explicación, ya sé como comparar los dos arreglos y agregarle información que falta con `array_merge()` sólo necesito poder separar los arreglos por cada barrido de información. :C

Comment: podrias agregar en el resultado de la consulta `padecimientos_diarios`

Comment: @VickMuñoz, otra posible solución sería resolver esto con una consulta `SQL`. Te dejo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/286443/16597) por si te interesa saber como. PD: en tu caso, las columnas dinámicas serían los padecimientos

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos por el link, creo que también era lo que necesitaba traerlo desde una consulta pero no sabía cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo así:

- Crear un arreglo para guardar la posición de la fechas (`eg: $fechasHash`) en el arreglo principal (`eg: $arr`)
- Al iterar los padecimientos y obtener las fechas, deberíamos:

  - Comprobar si la fecha ya existe en el arreglo principal, y en caso contrario, crear un arreglo de longitud igual al total de padecimientos + 1 (*columna `0` para la fecha*), agregarlo al arreglo principal y guardar la posición el `hash`
  - Finalmente asignar el `$valor['total']` en la "columna" `$i+1`

#### Ejemplo

```js
$arr = [];
$fechasHash = [];
$totalPad = count($c_diag);

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalPad; $i++) {

  $pad_totales_diarios = consultaBDRegresaArray('padecimientos_diarios', 'fecha, SUM(total) AS total', "fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' AND clave_padecimiento = $c_diag[$i] GROUP BY fecha ", 'A', false);
  foreach($pad_totales_diarios as $clave => $valor) {
    
    // Si la fecha aún no existe en el hash
    if (!isset($fechasHash[$valor['fecha']])) {
      $posicion = count($arr);
      $fechasHash[$valor['fecha']] = $posicion;
      
      // Creamos un arreglo lleno de ceros de logintud igual a la cantidad de padecimientos + 1
      $fecha = array_fill(0, $totalPad + 1, 0);
      // La primer "columna" es la fecha
      $fecha[0] = $valor['fecha'];
      $arr[] = $fecha;
    } else {
      // Obtenemos la posicion de la fecha
      $posicion = $fechasHash[$valor['fecha']];
    }
    
    // 
    $arr[$posicion][$i+1] = $valor['total'];
  }
}

var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta voy a ponerla en práctica regreso para comentar si funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$resultado = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($c_diag); $i++) { 

    $pad_totales_diarios = consultaBDRegresaArray('padecimientos_diarios','fecha, SUM(total) AS total',"fecha BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' AND clave_padecimiento = $c_diag[$i] GROUP BY fecha ", 'A', false);

    foreach ($pad_totales_diarios as $clave => $valor) {
        //obtenemos el a;o
        $fecha = date("Y",strtotime($valor['fecha']));
        // validamos que no exista la fecha en resultado
        if (!array_key_exists($fecha,$resultado)){
            // creamos un llave con el valor de la fecha
            // le agregamos dentro otra llave llamada total = total de los datos
            $resultado[$fecha] =array("total" => $valor['total'] );
            // creamos una llave dentro de fecha que se llame data
            $resultado[$fecha]["data"] = array();
            // agregamos a data el valor de padecimiento
            $resultado[$fecha]["data"][] = $valor['padecimientos_diarios'];
        }else{
            // si la llave ya existe
            // agregamos dentro de fecha->data el siguiente padecimiento
            $resultado[$fecha]["data"][] = $valor['padecimientos_diarios'];
        }

    }
}

echo json_encode($resultado,true);
```

el resultado seria algo como esto:

```
{
    "2017" : {"total" : 51, "data":[3.6, 2.3, 2.8]},
    "2018" : {"total" : 108, "data":[3.6, 7.1, 4.0, 4.1]} 

}
```

y solo lo recorreriamos asi:

```js
let data = {
    "2017" : {"total" : 51, "data":[3.6, 2.3, 2.8]},
    "2018" : {"total" : 108, "data":[3.6, 7.1, 4.0, 4.1]}
};

for(x in data){
console.log(`fecha: ${x} , total: ${data[x]["total"]}, data: [${data[x]["data"]}]`)
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta voy a ponerla en práctica regreso para comentar si funcionó.