# mostrar resultados de filas como columnas (transponer)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo 3 tablas

ordenes

```
+--+---------------+
|id|nombre_paciente|
+--+---------------+
|1 |juan           |
+--+---------------+
|2 |pedro          |
+--+---------------+
|3 |luis           |
+--+---------------+
|4 |jorge          |
+--+---------------+
```

examenes_ordenes

```
+--+---------+--------+
|id|examen_id|orden_id|
+--+---------+--------+
|1 |1        |1       |
+--+---------+--------+
|2 |2        |1       |
+--+---------+--------+
|3 |1        |2       |
+--+---------+--------+
|4 |2        |3       |
+--+---------+--------+
|5 |4        |4       |
+--+---------+--------+
```

examenes

```
+--+------+
|id|nombre|
+--+------+
|1 |EMO   |
+--+------+
|2 |AUDIO |
+--+------+
|3 |OPTO  |
+--+------+
|4 |ESPIRO|
+--+------+
```

necesito realizar una consulta de manera que los exámenes me los muestre como columnas. es decir

tabla_reporte

```
+--------+---------------+---+-----+----+------+
|orden_id|nombre_paciente|EMO|AUDIO|OPTO|ESPIRO|
+--------+---------------+---+-----+----+------+
|1       |juan           | 1 |  1  |    |      |
+--------+---------------+---+-----+----+------+
|2       |pedro          | 1 |     |    |      |
+--------+---------------+---+-----+----+------+
|3       |luis           |   |  1  |    |      |
+--------+---------------+---+-----+----+------+
|4       |jorge          |   |     |    |  1   |
+--------+---------------+---+-----+----+------+
```

Cabe aclarar que tengo 230 examenes y puede incrementar por lo que necesito que la consulta sea dinámica.
Ya lo habia realizado anteriormente en `access` con "`TRANSFORM`" pero no se como realizarlo en MySQL.

He buscardo en internet con count(case...) o con max(case...) pero no aplica para lo que necesito.

gracias de antemamo

Comment: Tendrias que pivotear la tabla no? como lo entiendo si por que si luego hay otro se debe de agregar a la derecha

Comment: Hola, tal vez te sirva revisar [¿Cómo puedo convertir una cierta fila a una columna en mysql?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/286412/77879)

Answer (score 0):

[image: resultado]

```
DECLARE @contador Int, @idpaciente Int, @nombreExamen varchar(50), 
@totalExamenesOrdenados Int, @totalExamenes Int
set @contador = 1
set @totalExamenesOrdenados = (select count(*) from examenordenes)
set @totalExamenes = (select COUNT(*) from examenes)
--CREE TABLA TEMPORAL CON SOLO TRES COLUMNAS
CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (idTemporal int not null identity(1,1) primary key, 
idpaciente int, nombrepaciente varchar(50))
WHILE @contador <= @totalExamenes
BEGIN
    --TOMO NOMBRE DEL EXAMEN Y DESPUÉS LO AGREGO A LA TABLA TEMPORAL QUE HABÍA CREADO
    SET @nombreExamen = (select nombre from examenes where idexamenes = @contador)
    execute ('ALTER TABLE #TablaTemporal ADD ' + @nombreExamen + ' VARCHAR(50)')
    SET @contador = + @contador + 1
END
--HAGO INSERT DE LOS NOMBRES DE TODOS LOS PACIENTES EN LA TABLA TEMPORAL NO IMPORTA 
--SI NO TIENEN EXAMENES ASIGNADOSS
Insert into #TablaTemporal (idpaciente, nombrepaciente) Select idOrdenes, 
nombrepaciente from ordenes
SET @contador = 1
WHILE @contador <= @totalExamenesOrdenados
BEGIN
    --TOMO ID DEL PACIENTE Y EL NOMBRE DEL EXAMEN QUE TIENE CADA REGISTRO DE LA TABLA 
    EXAMENORDENES
    SET @idpaciente = (select idorden from examenordenes where idexamenordenes = 
    @contador)
    SET @nombreExamen = (select nombre from examenordenes 
        inner join ordenes on examenordenes.idorden = ordenes.idordenes
        inner join examenes on examenordenes.idexamen = examenes.idexamenes where 
    examenordenes.idexamenordenes = @contador)
    print @idpaciente
    print @nombreExamen
    --HAGO UPDATE EN LA TABLA TEMPORAL EN LAS RESPECTIVAS COLUMNAS DE LOS EXAMENES
    execute('UPDATE #TablaTemporal set ' + @nombreExamen + ' = ''SI'' WHERE 
    idTemporal = ' + @idpaciente)
    SET @contador = @contador + 1
END
SET @contador = 1
WHILE @contador <= @totalExamenes
BEGIN
    --UN UPDATE SOLO PARA COLOCAR LA PALABRA NO EN LAS COLUMNAS QUE NO TIENEN 
    --PACIENTE ASIGNADO
    SET @nombreExamen = (select nombre from examenes where idexamenes = @contador)
    execute('UPDATE #TablaTemporal set ' + @nombreExamen + ' = ''NO'' WHERE ' + 
    @nombreExamen + ' IS NULL') 
    SET @contador = @contador + 1
END
select * from #TablaTemporal
```